# Add apostrophe in front of a number in sas

Tags: sas

I want to add an apostrophe in front of a variable - number in sas so that the output in excel appears as a proper number and not in scientific notations

proc SQL;
  create table PERM.accounts as
  select distinct
input(LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO, $30.)   as 'Account No'n but this results in numbers like this in excel: 1.23456E+12 - but I need the output to look like this: 1234567891234
the way to trick excel is to put an apostrophe in front of the number like: '1234567891234
how do I code this in proc sql?

```
 ,input(LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO, best32.)   as 'Account No'n
,input(LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO, $30.)   as 'Account No'n
```

how can I append LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO using a `catx` statement within the proc sql function?

More code (from comment)

```
%SASSTARTUP; 
%macro EXPORT_MAIL (
  IN_DSNAME=PERM.FINAL_&END_CURR_MTH,
  CSV_FNAME=DATA_&END_CURR_MTH
);
  proc EXPORT 
    data=&IN_DSNAME 
    outfile="&OUTPUT_DATA_DIR.\&CSV_FNAME..csv" 
    dbms=CSV 
    replace label;
  run;
  filename myfile EMAIL 
    to=("&EMAIL_RECIP_1.") 
    from=(‘ @ ‘) 
    replyto=(‘ @ ‘)
    subject=("Sample")
    attach=(
      "&OUTPUT_DATA_DIR.\&CSV_FNAME..csv"
      content_type='application/excel'
    )
  ;

  data NULL; 
    file myfile; 
    put ' '; 
    put "The latest Sample is attached."; 
    put ' ';
  run;
%mend EXPORT_MAIL;
```

Comment: What is the data type for loan account no in the source?

Comment: it is a character variable

Comment: I tried now: ,catx(  "'" , LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO )   as 'Account No'n  which works for SAS but excel puts it back into scientific notation

Comment: Can you show how you are exporting the file to excel?

Comment: %SASSTARTUP;
%macro EXPORT_MAIL (IN_DSNAME=PERM.FINAL_&END_CURR_MTH,
                    CSV_FNAME=DATA_&END_CURR_MTH );
  proc EXPORT data=&IN_DSNAME
              outfile="&OUTPUT_DATA_DIR.\&CSV_FNAME..csv"
              dbms=CSV
              replace
              label;
  run;
  filename myfile EMAIL 
   to=("&EMAIL_RECIP_1." )
  from=(‘ @ ‘)
  replyto=(‘ @ ‘))
  subject=("Sample") 
  attach=("&OUTPUT_DATA_DIR.\&CSV_FNAME..csv"
            content_type='application/excel');
 ;
...

Comment: upps hardly readable

Comment: ...   data _NULL_;
    file myfile;
    put ' ';
    put "The latest Sample is attached."; 
    put ' ';
  run; 
%mend EXPORT_MAIL;

Comment: I export the whole file in an automated process. therefore the format needs to be right beforehand

Comment: can I 'append' within the proc sql? Or do I have to do a dataset for this one variable??

Comment: Don't let Excel decide whether the column is numeric or character.  Don't just let it open the CSV file.  Instead use the menu in Excel to open the file and you can then tell it what format each column has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating csv attachments that are to be opened with Excel, the question is more one of ["Long number in CSV file appearing in scientific notation by default"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/64c1ee52-eb53-4202-bb27-d9b08d3bd60a/long-number-in-csv-file-appearing-in-scientific-notation-by-default), which says a text formula in the csv will be honored by Excel during default Open actions of a csv.

You can also force SAS Proc Export to output a double quoted character value by appending a hard-space character (xA0) to the account number.

Example:

```
data have;
  acct = '123456789012345';
  accnum = input(acct,best32.);
  acctsq = cats("'",acct);

  acctweak = strip(acct)||byte(160);
  acctdqformula = cats('=TEXT(',acct,',"0")');
run;

proc export data=have outfile="c:\temp\sandbox.csv" dbms=csv replace label;
run;

options noxwait noxsync xmin;
%sysexec start "Open Excel" excel c:\temp\sandbox.csv;
```

So your SQL statement that creates `PERM.FINAL_&END_CURR_MTH` can have

```
, strip(LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO)||byte(160) as 'Account No'n
, cats('=TEXT(',LOAN_ACCOUNT_NO,',"0")') as 'Account No'n
```

**or**

create an Excel file for attachment

```
ODS EXCEL file = "&OUTPUT_DATA_DIR.\&CSV_FNAME..xlsx";
proc PRINT data=&IN_DSNAME;
ODS EXCEL CLOSE;

… attach &CSV_FNAME..xlsx with content type application/ms-excel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ODS instead of PROC EXPORT:

```
ODS tagsets.ExcelXP FILE = "DATA_&END_CURR_MTH..xml";

proc print data=PERM.FINAL_&END_CURR_MTH;
  format .....;
run;
```

Set your formats appropriately in the print statement.